# PV system Exchange rapid shut down switch by fuses

Tags: solar-panels

On the roof of my stand alone garage I have 60 solar pv panels, 2 inverters with each 3 strings of panels. So there are 10 panels on each string.
The installer installed one rapid shut down switch for each system with only 2 switched contacts, although there are 3 switched contacts drawn on the diagram. So he combined 2 strings and one string on each RSD switch. Now the switches give problems after 5 years and he wants to replace the RSD switch by fuses.
Also run the 4 extra wires, so each string will be separately connected to the inverters. Is the exchange of RSD switch by fuses allowed in Florida?

Comment: Hi Peter, is it possible for you to sketch it and post an image.

Comment: If rapid shutdown is required (and it usually is) fuses are clearly not the same function. Evidently Florida adopted NEC2017 in 2020, so a rapid shutdown not at the module level (which is the type you have) would have been compliant to NEC2014 when the system was installed. Presumably you can repair that system without upgrading to NEC2017 requirements, but without something like a big insulated lever to pull all the fuses I can't see fuses as a one-for-one replacement of RSD switches.

Comment: What did the installer put in for a RSD system/modules, or are the RSD switches simply routed to the string inverters?